# Is there a plain KDE version without all the KDE applications available for Ubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde-apps

I really like KDE and Ubuntu but I don't need most of the KDE applications, like Kontact or Kopete that will be installed with the usual KDE.

Is there a way I can install KDE (4.7) without all those applications? It makes more sense to manually install the ones I actually use (like Konsole) than uninstalling many.

Comment: Install `plasma-desktop` and then install whatever applications you want.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --no-recommends kubuntu-desktop
or if you already have KDE installed, manually remove all the KDE applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends kubuntu-desktop`

Answer (score 2):

The https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages is telling:

> kde-base: This metapackage includes the nucleus of KDE, namely the
>   minimal package set necessary to run KDE as a desktop environment.
>   This includes the window manager, taskbar, control center, a text
>   editor, file manager, web browser, X terminal emulator, and many other
>   programs and components.

There has been package naming changes. I think that this is the current nucleus of the KDE:

> kde-baseapps
>
> Description: base applications from the official KDE release
>   (meta-package) ... This package provides core applications for the KDE
>   4 desktop.

The kde-baseapps is depending:

- dolphin
- kde-baseapps-bin
- kdepasswd
- kfind
- konqueror
- plasma-widget-folderview

These may be useful:

- [How to completely remove desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop)
- [How to remove all traces of KDE installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79636/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-kde-installed)

Answer (score 0):

[Kubuntu 18.04.0 LTS](https://kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/) now includes a minimal install. For fresh installs, I think this is a good alternative.

If you already have Ubuntu installed, like in your question, then `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends kubuntu-desktop` is your answer.