# Remove KILE and other KDE dependencies

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, kde, dependencies, kile

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I found my root directory full so thought to free up some space.
In this regard I opt for removing **KILE**. But the base package **KILE** is only 4.4 MB.

How can I remove its related libraries (nearly 300MB) which were installed with it?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge kile
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

This should remove any leftover KDE dependencies (as long as there is no other KDE program installed, that depends on them)

Comment: with first command it removes only 4.4 mb space kile package.. and then show 0 to remove

Answer (score 1):

You can list the kde-depencies with `dpkg -l | grep kde`. Output is something like this:

```
rc  kdebase-bin              4:4.6.5-0ubuntu1    core binaries for the KDE base applications
rc  kdebase-workspace-bin    4:4.6.5-0ubuntu1    core binaries for the KDE Plasma Workspace
```

Now you can manually remove all unwanted kde packages, but **be careful** if there are packages that not belongs to kde. If you use other kde applications, then those applications need kde-depencies.

**See:** [What do the various dpkg flags like 'ii' 'rc' mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean)

Answer (score 0):

To remove KDE libraries, use command below. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) then type:

```
sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop --purge  
sudo apt-get remove kde-base --purge
```

Then restart your computer. The KDE libraries will be removed.

Comment: Can you explain what those commands do?