# How to Remove KDE Login Screen?

Tags: 12.04, apt, kubuntu, kde, display-manager

I *accidentally* installed KDE on my Ubuntu 12.04 Machine the other day, to find I really don't have a liking for it. I runned a apt-get command to remove the **kde-full** package, but programs like **Konsole**, **Kmouth**, and the KDE login screen still remained on my machine. I've looked at other posts on this community, but none of the methods have worked for me so far. Somebody has recommended to use an apt-get command to remove all traces, but this what I recieved:

> Virtual packages like 'kdepim-groupware' can't be removed
>   Virtual packages like 'mysql-client-core-5.1' can't be removed
>   Virtual packages like 'mysql-server-core-5.1' can't be removed
>   Virtual packages like 'plasma-widget-kimpanel-backend-ibus' can't be removed
>   E: Unable to locate package kdepim-wizards
>   E: Unable to locate package libattica0
>   E: Unable to locate package libgps19
>   E: Unable to locate package libkwineffects1abi2
>   E: Unable to locate package libkworkspace4
>   E: Unable to locate package libokularcore1
>   E: Unable to locate package libplasmaclock4abi2
>   E: Unable to locate package libtaskmanager4abi2
>   E: Unable to locate package libzip1

I really don't care, I currently use Unity and GNOME and I don't mind if KDE sits there. But, it would be nice to return to the default login screen.

Comment: I've got the same issue, tried [the answers here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79636/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-kde-installed) as well as on [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/73993/how-to-completely-remove-desktop) and none work, I'll bounty as soon as possible if noone has posted before then.

Comment: I've seen the first one, tried the command for the most popular answer, you can see the output above. I've willing to bounty if this doesn't work out.

Comment: Whats strange is in my case I used that command and it "worked" without any bugs, but when I log in I get the kde login, I just prefer unity's aesthetic looks for the login screen but its strange...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure kdm`

there should be a menu popping up, asking you which the default display manager should be.

Then restart your PC.

Comment: Tried it already, set it to `lightdm` but unfortunately didn't work in my case, I'm guessing sharksfan98 will also have already tried.

Comment: @Oyibo you should also type `sudo restart lightdm` after choosing I suppose

Comment: It said that package gdm is not installed and no info is available. Should I download that file? Is it in the universal repository?

Comment: sorry i ninja-edited it, it reads as **kdm** now xD

Comment: Oh... Changed it to lightdm and restarted it, but then received "restart: Unknown instance:"

Comment: @Geckobear just tried it and unfortunately didn't change a thing in my case :(

Comment: @sharksfan98 try restarting your PC after selecting lightdm.

Comment: Great! You can now accept the answer so other people can get help if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the kde programs:

```
sudo apt-get purge kdm kubuntu-desktop (or kde-full as needed)
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To reset the Ubuntu boot theme:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

then choose the option you want. Follow this with:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Run

```
sudo update-grub
```

before rebooting. This should also set the login screen back.

Comment: Good additional steps to take in order to wipe out more traces of KDE, but in order to answer the initial question - about the login screen - I would recommend adding `kdm` to the list of packages to remove (to be sure).