# Ubuntu shows 'Kubuntu' on boot

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, 13.04, plymouth

I recently updated my Ubuntu 12.10 setup to 13.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

After going through the process and rebooting, I was a little confused by the GRUB menu showing a "Kubuntu" option instead of "Ubuntu" as it usually did.

After choosing it, it then shows me a Kubuntu splash screen during the bootup (consisting just of a blue "Kubuntu"), but the subsequent login screen and desktop are fine.

I do have a KDE setup besides Unity (I had installed `kubuntu-desktop` way earlier when I was running 12.04), but I don't see why it should have affected the GRUB menu and the bootup splash screen!

Comment: Wow that is really crazy :-)  Since it is only the splash screen does it bother you?

Comment: @Freedom_Ben: Not really, although when I first saw the modified entry in GRUB, I was terrified that I'd lost my setup.

Comment: ubuntu + kubuntu-desktop _is_ essentially kubuntu.

Comment: if you are talking about the screens upto and including login - but not after that, then try removing kdm - i think you want lightdm

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change Plymouth Splash Screen.

This is the initial splash screen you see at bootup. Different Plymouth themes can be found by searching for plymouth-theme in a Package Manager. Install a new one and manually select the theme you wish to use. The default Ubuntu theme is already installed.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: works great also on 15.04

Comment: tested in 16.04 work well!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you haven't removed `kubuntu-desktop` completely.

You can just remove the splash `sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-artwork-usplash` and start enjoying  Raring Ringtail

Comment: I just removed `kubuntu-desktop`, and all that did was uninstall a ~54 kb app, after which the issue still exists. `kubuntu-artwork-splash` doesn't appear to exist on my system, but in the login screen, I can still choose to log in to the KDE Plasma Workspace.

Comment: Note that removing a meta-package doesn't force removal of all of its "Depends" (prerequisite packages). Also: it doesn't remove config files.  `man apt-get` for details.  So by removing kubuntu-desktop you haven't really removed any actual packages. Try `dpkg-query  -f '${Depends}' --show kubuntu-desktop` to see all its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Default value of variable GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR is set to 
`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian` by */etc/default/grub* script while generating grub.cfg.

Check your */etc/default/grub.d/* directory for scripts which could overwrite this variable.

In my case it was */etc/default/grub.d/50_kubuntu.cfg* which has been created by KDE Plasma Environment so I deleted it and generated *grub.cfg* again.

To solve this problem with GRUB, simply type into terminal:

```
sudo rm /etc/default/grub.d/50_kubuntu.cfg
sudo update-grub
```