# Unistalling Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, uninstall

A while ago, I installed Kubuntu because I heard rumors that it ran faster than Ubuntu. Well, I found that to not be true on my machine. Since I got Kubuntu from the terminal, is there a way to uninstall it, without uninstalling Ubuntu? Thanks!!!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu ? 12.10 ? See http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu. Also, installing a fresh install of kubuntu is not the same thing as adding kubuntu-desktop to an existing install.

Comment: I just upgraded to 13.02 today. I assume it would be the same? I installed the kubuntu-desktop, I think. When I start up, I see the Kubuntu logo when I start up.

Comment: See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/79636/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-kde-installed

Comment: Well, again, an upgrade and installing kubuntu-desktop is not going to be the same as a fresh install of kubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just backup your data and do fresh installation. Trying to remove KDE and then putting back Gnome/Unity will cost you more than fresh installation will.

Comment: Also, if a fresh install is slow, we would need to know what hardware you have. Likely a video or other driver problem.

Answer (score 1):

The KDE desktop meta-package is in the Ubuntu Universe repository as `kubuntu-desktop`.
If you want to remove KDE and get back to Ubuntu's pseudo-original state, open up your terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop
```

This will remove KDE from your system, and reinstall Unity. You will not have to uninstall Ubuntu in the process.

Note that you may have to run a distribution upgrade, as Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) has recently been released. This can be accomplished with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling the meta package will not uninstall kubuntu from your computer. It will just remove the meta package itself and all other KDE stuff will remain in your computer. So, speaking from experience, a fresh install seems to be the least painful option.