# Cannot revert back to Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am new in linux world. I had ubuntu 13.04 installed. Some days ago I have installed "kde" in ubuntu 13.04 and after restart it became "kubuntu". I did not like it and tried to revert back to ubuntu 13.04, but can't do it. I have tried solution from the following links

1. [How to remove all traces of KDE installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79636/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-kde-installed)
2. http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/purexubuntu

None of those solution work for me, I get these errors:

- http://pastebin.com/h6zDSL76

I have also tried these following commands

1. `sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop`
2. `sudo apt-get autoremove`

At last I have used following command

```
sudo apt-get remove akonadi-facebook akregator amarok amarok-common amarok-utils apport-kde apturl-kde ark audiocd-kio bluedevil calligra-data calligra-libs cdparanoia cdrdao colord-kde cryptsetup dolphin dragonplayer freespacenotifier gnupg-agent gnupg2 gpgsm gstreamer0.10-qapt gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen gwenview ibus-qt4 k3b k3b-data kaccessible kaddressbook kamera kamoso kate kcalc kde-base-artwork kde-baseapps-bin kde-baseapps-data kde-config-gtk-style kde-config-tablet kde-config-telepathy-accounts kde-config-touchpad kde-style-oxygen kde-telepathy kde-telepathy-approver kde-telepathy-auth-handler kde-telepathy-contact-list kde-telepathy-data kde-telepathy-desktop-applets kde-telepathy-filetransfer-handler kde-telepathy-integration-module kde-telepathy-minimal kde-telepathy-send-file kde-telepathy-text-ui kde-wallpapers-default kde-window-manager kde-window-manager-common kde-workspace kde-workspace-bin kde-workspace-data kde-workspace-kgreet-plugins kde-zeroconf kdegames-card-data kdegames-data kdegraphics-strigi-analyzer kdemultimedia-kio-plugins kdenetwork-filesharing kdepasswd kdepim-kresources kdepim-strigi-plugins kdesudo kexi khelpcenter4 kinfocenter kio-mtp klipper kmag kmail kmenuedit kmix kmousetool knotes konsole kontact korganizer kpat kppp krdc krita krita-data kscreen ksnapshot ksysguard ksysguardd ksystemlog ktorrent ktorrent-data ktouchpadenabler kubuntu-desktop kubuntu-firefox-installer kubuntu-notification-helper kubuntu-settings-desktop kubuntu-settings-netbook kubuntu-web-shortcuts kwalletmanager libakonadi-socialutils4 libassuan0 libaudiocdplugins4 libbluedevil1 libcalendarsupport4 libchm1 libcln6 libdebconf-kde0 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libepub0 libeventviews4 libfftw3-double3 libflac++6 libgpgme++2 libgps20 libgrantlee-core0 libgrantlee-gui0 libgtlcore0.8 libgtlfragment0.8 libhomerun0 libibus-qt1 libincidenceeditorsng4 libindicate-qt1 libindicate5 libiso9660-8 libk3b6 libkateinterfaces4 libkblog4 libkcddb4 libkcompactdisc4 libkdcraw-data libkdcraw22 libkdecorations4abi1 libkdegames6 libkdepim4 libkdepimdbusinterfaces4 libkdgantt2 libkephal4abi1 libkexiv2-11 libkexiv2-data libkfbapi1 libkipi-data libkipi10 libkleo4 libkmanagesieve4 libkonq-common libkonq5-templates libkonq5abi1 libkontactinterface4 libkpgp4 libkrossui4 libksane-data libksane0 libksba8 libkscreen0 libkscreensaver5 libksgrd4 libksieve4 libksieveui4 libksignalplotter4 libktnef4 libktorrent-l10n libktorrent5 libktpchat0 libktpcommoninternalsprivate5 libkunitconversion4 libkwineffects1abi4 libkwinglutils1abi1 libkwinnvidiahack4 libkworkspace4abi2 liblastfm1 liblightdm-qt-2-0 libllvm3.0 libloudmouth1-0 libmailcommon4 libmailimporter4 libmessagecomposer4 libmessagecore4 libmessagelist4 libmessageviewer4 libmpcdec6 libmuonprivate1 libmusicbrainz5-0 libmygpo-qt1 libnepomukwidgets4 libokularcore2abi1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenconnect2 libopenjpeg2 libopenshiva0.8 libpimcommon4 libplasma-geolocation-interface4 libplasmaclock4abi3 libplasmagenericshell4 libprocesscore4abi1 libprocessui4a libqaccessibilityclient0 libqalculate5 libqalculate5-data libqca2-plugin-ossl libqgpgme1 libqimageblitz4 libqoauth1 libqtglib-2.0-0 libqtgstreamer-0.10-0 libqtgstreamerui-0.10-0 libqtscript4-core libqtscript4-gui libqtscript4-network libqtscript4-sql libqtscript4-uitools libqtscript4-xml libqtshiva0.1 libreoffice-kde libreoffice-style-oxygen libruby1.9.1 libsolidcontrol4abi2 libsolidcontrolifaces4abi2 libspnav0 libsyndication4 libtag-extras1 libtaskmanager4abi3 libtelepathy-logger-qt4-1 libtelepathy-qt4-2 libtemplateparser4 libvcdinfo0 libweather-ion6 libxcb-damage0 libyaml-0-2 libzip2 lightdm-kde-greeter muon muon-installer muon-notifier muon-updater okular okular-extra-backends oxygen-cursor-theme partitionmanager pinentry-gtk2 pinentry-qt4 plasma-dataengines-addons plasma-dataengines-workspace plasma-desktop plasma-netbook plasma-scriptengine-python plasma-widget-facebook plasma-widget-folderview plasma-widget-homerun plasma-widget-kimpanel plasma-widget-menubar plasma-widget-networkmanagement plasma-widgets-addons plasma-widgets-workspace plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text print-manager python-pyudev python3-dbus.mainloop.qt python3-pykde4 python3-pyqt4 python3-sip qapt-deb-installer quassel quassel-data rdesktop rekonq ruby ruby1.9.1 scdaemon skanlite software-properties-kde systemsettings tasks-icons ttf-oxygen-font-family ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt usb-creator-kde userconfig vcdimager && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

This command have removed lots of programs along with programs of kde, I could see that in the terminal, but I am frustrated that command also could not remove kubuntu, still graphics of kubuntu exists in every where (during login, name, desktop everywhere).

What can be the solution? Do I have to reinstall ubuntu 13.04? I don't wanna do that cause I have installed lots of programs and set up many settings... Anyone help pease....

Comment: you want to remove the logo only, or also the kde, or you can't log in to unity.. can you be more specific ? thanks :)

Comment: @Rodislav i want to remove whole kde and return my ubuntu. i can login to unity, there is no problem with that... after i have installed kde, i cannot acces any of my drives (ntfs).

Comment: ok, try to follow instructions from link which gave @bodhi.zazen 
if this is not working, write here :)

Comment: Your problem with accessing your ntfs drive is almost certainly unrelated to KDE.

Comment: @Rodislav: i have tried bodhi.zazen's solution, but still not working, i have tried several times, just showing "could not fount ...."... I also tried "sudo apt-get autoremove" and "sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop" this two commands did something but kubuntu not removed

Comment: Can you add any detail about the "could not found" error?

Comment: @JorgeCastro:  see this link please....http://pastebin.com/h6zDSL76

Comment: @Rodislav : can you please help? check this error please http://pastebin.com/h6zDSL76

Comment: @bodhi.zazen : can you please help? check this error please http://pastebin.com/h6zDSL76

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I can help you with, this, can you try to reinstall the system ? (if it's possible, of course)

Comment: @Rodislav: I don't want that, unless I'm bound to.... thanks for your reply