# Kubuntu instead of Ubuntu on Grub

Tags: 13.04, grub2, kubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 13.04. Then I installed too KDE Plasma Environment. Then I removed KDE. Everything went fine. I can now log with Ubuntu (Unity).

Only (small) remaining problem: on the boot page (Grub), the command line does not show "Ubuntu 13.04" but "Kubuntu 13.04". Is there a way to fix this little inconvenience? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Default value of variable **GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR** is set to 
`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian` by */etc/default/grub* script while generating grub.cfg.

Check your */etc/default/grub.d/* directory for scripts which could overwrite this variable.

In my case it was */etc/default/grub.d/50_kubuntu.cfg* which has been created by KDE Plasma Environment so I deleted it and generated *grub.cfg* again.

To solve this problem, simply type into terminal:

```
sudo rm /etc/default/grub.d/50_kubuntu.cfg
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Nice answer, but could you expand your answer and explain what happens as you do this, it may help people with a similar problem in the future.

Comment: I edited my answer so I hope it will help better understand why it happens..

Answer (score 0):

Just run in a [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal) the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If still the problem persist, run:

```
sudo sed -i 's/Kubuntu/Ubuntu/g' /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

You can also see:

- [How to Completely Uninstall / Remove kde-plasma-desktop](http://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-12-04/ubuntu-12-04-how-to-completely-uninstall-remove-kde-plasma-desktop)
- [How to remove all traces of KDE installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79636/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-kde-installed)

Comment: Thanks for supporting. The first command (sudo update-grub) did not change anything.
The second command (sudo sed -i 's/Kubuntu/Ubuntu/g' /boot/grub/grub.cfg) changed the line in the "Grub page" (Ubuntu instead of Kubuntu) but the following page is still displaying "Kubuntu 13.04". After this, I reach normally the login page.

Comment: The answer is:

Ubuntu GNU/Linux
Advanced options for Ubuntu GNU/Linux
Memory test (memtest86+)
Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)

Comment: @SwissEagle What is the result of `grep -E '^menuentry|^submenu' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | cut -d '"' -f2 | cut -d "'" -f2` command?

Comment: The answer to your last question is just above it. Anyway, thanks again for helping. I did it all again. The Grub shows "Ubuntu" but the next page still displays "Kubuntu 13.04" (even if everything is proper "Ubuntu" after this).

Comment: @SwissEagle I edited my answer.

Comment: @ Radu: I entered the command `sudo apt-get autoremove` then checked in Synaptic. It seems as there is no KDE leftovers  anymore. The system seems clean but... after the Grub, I still got that "Kubuntu 13.04" page before I can reach the login page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the kernel and initrd images (`vmlinuz-*` , `initrd.img-*` ). Try reinstalling your kernels and it might fix the problem.