# How to return the login screen of the original unity ubuntu?

Tags: unity, lightdm, login-screen

I've installed the LightDM GTK+ Greeter 1.7.0 as below

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lightdm-gtk-greeter-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

(http://www.smdavis.us/2013/12/28/lightdm-gtk-greeter-1-7-0-released/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=lightdm-gtk-greeter-1-7-0-released&utm_reader=feedly)

Now I want to return to the original login screen of unity ubuntu. Please show me a way.
Tasks done but have no result:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:lightdm-gtk-greeter-team/stable.
sudo apt-fast remove lightdm-gtk-greeter
sudo apt-fast install --reinstall lightdm.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First purge the package and remove the PPA.

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm-gtk-greeter*
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:lightdm-gtk-greeter-team/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

Then edit the file that reads the greeter.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-ubuntu.conf
```

change this line `greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter` to this `greeter-session=unity-greeter`

if the line above does not exist, add it.

if above file/path does not exits (depends on Ubuntu version) try this one

```
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Then reconfigure both DM and greeter

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm unity-greeter
```

Reboot your PC.

Comment: My platform Ubuntu 13.10: apply to gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf. Quite success.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 15.04, there was only one file in `/etc/lightdm`, `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`. So instead I just did `sudo apt-get purge lightdm-gtk-greeter` (it had installed it from the official repos so I didn't actually have to remove any PPAs), then did `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm unity-greeter`. After that, it worked. I actually think that you may not even have to do the `dpkg-reconfigure` step, but I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 5):

Edit your `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file, and make sure that the greeter-session is set to unity-greeter, so there has to be a line like the following:

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Comment: This answer is best for any users who do not wish to uninstall any packages.