# How to go back from plasma to unity

Tags: 16.04, unity, kubuntu, kde, lightdm

I use Ubuntu 16.04.5. I had decided to try Plasma 5 desktop and did this:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

I've kept `lightdm` during installation.
After the process finished I faced several problems with Plasma 5: It loaded dramatically slow and showed several windows with error messages. Moreover it ate 70% of my RAM which is ~2.5 Gb.

I had switched to Unity in login manager and deleted Plasma:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
 sudo apt purge kubuntu-desktop
 sudo apt autoremove
```

But it looks some parts of kde are still in my system: I see KDE default cursor in login manager and in some Qt applications and when I turn on my computer I see `Kubuntu` logo instead of `Ubuntu`. I can live with startup logo but appearance of KDE cursor sometimes is annoying. How to fix it?

Comment: KDE or more precisely Qt apps you installed (not as part of kubuntu-desktop) will remain as you installed them, until you uninstall (remove/purge) them. The Kubuntu logo you see is the plymouth screen added by Kubuntu but it's only a graphic/wallpaper and not a program and can be changed - refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/2007/how-do-i-change-the-plymouth-bootscreen  *fyi:  Using GTK+ apps/tools in a Qt environment (ie. KDE/LXQt/..) will cause multiple libs that do the same thing to be in memory (both GTK+ & Qt) which wastes memory..*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your **cursor issue**:
Delete the package `breeze-cursor-theme` and it's dependencies with this command:

```
sudo apt purge breeze-cursor-theme --autoremove
```

---

To change the **boot logo**, run this command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

You should see a list with available logo options. Chose the one you want.

After that you can delete the kubuntu "boot logo" package with this command:

```
sudo apt purge plymouth-theme-kubuntu-logo --autoremove
```

---

Just a **tip**: With this command, you can list KDE related packages:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i KDE
```

(But be careful with deleting them.)

Answer (score 2):

See if this may help:

[How to remove all traces of KDE installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79636/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-kde-installed)

- This link shows how to remove the PPA:

https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge kubuntu-ppa/backports
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/925988)

Comment: Made the correction, the first link is from this website. Thanks for the clarification.